# Matlab: How to close program legaly?

Tags: matlab, function, handle

I have a running script with many graphical handles that I update here and there in the code.
My aim is that when I close the program brutaly (with X button or Ctrl C) to close it correctly.

I've overridden the default close function, yet when sometimes I still get "Invalid object handle" when pressing it or when pressing Ctrl+C.

I have many handles in the code, should check each one or is there another method of closing the figure and the code correctly? (Something like 'quit' but with out closing matlab IDE).

Thanks,
Guy.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the validity of a `handle` with `isvalid`. You should loop over your handles, check their validity, and close them if valid; you should probably also chuck a `try...catch` in there for good measure. Something like:

```
function figure1_DeleteFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    errList = [];
    for nHndl = 1:length(handles.myHandles)
        if isvalid(handles.myHandles(nHndl))
            try
                delete(handles.myHandles(nHndl));
            catch err
                errList = [errList err];
            end
        end
    end

    if length(errList) == 1
        error([mfilename ':ErrorClosingUI'], 'Error closing UI : %s', errList.message);
    elseif length(errList) > 1
        % Should probably do something smarter with the error messages here
        error([mfilename ':ErrorClosingUI'], 'Multiple errors occurred closing UI');
    end
```